# listview refresh in android databinding

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-alertdialog, android-databinding

I am working with one of application using android MVVM architecture with databinding concepts.

The problem is when i am updating the textview of the xml the entire view gets updated.so listview gets refreshed and scroll to top position.i want to restrict the listview when onItem click event occurs.

Following xml contains listview.

```
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>

            <variable
                name="kenoservicesVM"
                type="com.naushad.kenocustomer.landing.KenoServicesVM" />
            <variable
                name="kenoservice"
                type="com.naushad.kenocustomer.landing.KenoService" />

        </data>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/nliveo_transparent"
            android:paddingEnd="20sp"
            android:paddingStart="20sp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="160sp"
                    android:layout_margin="0sp"
                    android:background="@color/nliveo_transparent"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:scrollbars="none">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/lstServices"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onItemClick="@{kenoservicesVM::onItemClick}"
                        bind:items="@{kenoservicesVM.mList}">

                    </ListView>
                    <!--android:onItemClick="@{kenoservicesVM::onItemClick}"-->
                </ScrollView>
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Total"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/totalCharges"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"

                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                    <!--android:text="@{kenoservicesVM.totalPrice ?? @string/_0_aed}"-->

                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/your_btn_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/bgNext"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                        android:alpha="0.5"
                        android:src="@drawable/blue_round_light_bg" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_add_card"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                        android:background="@drawable/blue_next_bg" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </layout>
```

Following viewmodel class indicates the viewmodel which i have used in xml.

```
public class KenoServicesVM extends BaseObservable {
    public ObservableArrayList<KenoService> mList = new ObservableArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;
    @NonNull
    private String mTotalPrice;
    int selectedServiceCharges=0;
    private int bar;

    public ObservableField<String> price;
    Handler handler;

    public KenoServicesVM(List<KenoService> list, Context mContext) {
        mList.addAll(list);
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getTotalPrice() {
        return mTotalPrice;
    }

    public void setTotalPrice(@NonNull String totalPrice) {
        this.mTotalPrice = totalPrice;
//        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.kenoservicesVM);
//        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.totalPrice);
        notifyChange();
//        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.kenoservicesVM);
    }

    @BindingAdapter("bind:items")
    public static void bindList(ListView view, ObservableArrayList<KenoService> list) {
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(list);
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int position, long arg3) {
        if(position == 0) return;
        if(mList.get(position).getSelected())
            mList.get(position).setSelected(false);
        else
            mList.get(position).setSelected(true);


        for (int i=0 ;i<mList.size();i++){
            KenoService keno = mList.get(i);
            if(keno.getSelected())
                selectedServiceCharges +=Integer.parseInt(keno.getKenoServiceCharge());
        }
        /*handler =  new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        price = new ObservableField<>(selectedServiceCharges +" AED");
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();*/

        setTotalPrice(selectedServiceCharges  +" AED");
//        dialogueServicesBinding.totalCharges.setText(selectedServiceCharges +" AED");

//        mTotalPrice = selectedServiceCharges +" AED";
//        ModuleManager.startActivity(ModuleManager.DISPATCH_MODULE, DispatchModule.STATE_FORGOTPASSWORD, (Activity) mContext);
    }
}
```

I am new to android databinding concepts.Please help me to resolve this issue when i click on listview item and refreshing the view.Thanks in advance.

Comment: OnitemClickListener having the method setTotalPrice(),this method calls notifyChange().so because of this entire view will gets updated.please check it once and let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Bindable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/Bindable.html) for your properties.

```
@NonNull
@Bindable
public String getTotalPrice() {
    return mTotalPrice;
}
```

This will create the `BR.totalPrice` field and you'll be able to call

```
notifyPropertyChanged(BR.totalPrice);
```

and the text should update with it

```
android:text="@{kenoservicesVM.totalPrice ?? @string/_0_aed}"
```

Additionally `@NonNull` is a promise you might not be able to hold. Consider adding a default value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't leave a comment due to reputation but I have bumped into one of the similar problem before, you can pass mList and position in your setTotalPrice methods and then called notifyItemChanged instead of notifyChange, this way it will update only the item at the specified position in your list

```
public void setTotalPrice(@NonNull String totalPrice, int position, ObservableArrayList<KenoService> mList, TextView totalCharges) {
    this.mTotalPrice = totalPrice;
    mList.notifyItemChanged(position);
    totalCharges.setText(//whatever u need here);
    totalCharges.invalidate(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for giving reply.listview item refresh works perfectly but i want to update textview outside of the listview in same xml,so at that time its also getting updated.I want to update "total charges" textview.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully it will suite your need, basically when you call view.invalidate(), it will tell the view to redraw itself with your new data that you have binded. Let me know if this work :)